# How do I get Magento Cron Jobs running on my test site?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, cron, reindex, cpanel

I recently transferred all of my data from my `Magento 1.9.1` to `Magento 2.1.7.`

The data transfer went fine, but I can't reindex the data therefore not allowing me to access products and categories. The error is within the cron jobs and I've tried every solution I've found online but nothing work for me.

My original site is in: `my username/public_html/` folder and my new site is in: `username/public_html/magetest/` where I only see **cron.php** in the `public_html/magetest/pub/` folder.

Can someone help me to find out the correct commands to enter in `cpanel cronjobs ?`

Answer (score 1):

You can use below example to set cron for your magento 2 and you can check cron log in your magento/var/setup.cron.log and update.cron.log file

```
php7 -f /<username>/public_html/magetest/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /<username>/public_html/magetest/var/log/magento.cron.log
php7 -f /<username>/public_html/magetest/update/cron.php >> /<username>/public_html/magetest/var/log/update.cron.log
php7 -f /<username>/public_html/magetest/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /<username>/public_html/magetest/var/log/setup.cron.log
```

You can review below links for more information

https://www.properhost.com/support/kb/41/How-to-Configure-Magento-2-Cron-Jobs

https://community.magento.com/t5/Hosting-Performance/Configuring-cron-job-for-siteground/m-p/37339#M31